# Как заставить javascript работать на resize window

Tags: javascript, jquery

Скрипт работает на load, а на resize нет ...

```
      setTimeout(function() {
      var mainDivs = jQuery(".column"); //Получаем все элементы с классом column
      var maxHeight = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < mainDivs.length; ++i) {
        if (maxHeight < jQuery(mainDivs[i]).height()) { //Находим максимальную высоту
          maxHeight = jQuery(mainDivs[i]).height(); 
        }
      }
      for (var i = 0; i < mainDivs.length; ++i) {
        jQuery(mainDivs[i]).height(maxHeight); //Устанавливаем всем элементам максимальную высоту
      }
    }, 1000);

jQuery(window).on('load resize',setTimeout);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
function myfunction (){
  setTimeout(function() {
      var mainDivs = jQuery(".column"); //Получаем все элементы с классом column
      var maxHeight = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < mainDivs.length; ++i) {
        if (maxHeight < jQuery(mainDivs[i]).height()) { //Находим максимальную высоту
          maxHeight = jQuery(mainDivs[i]).height(); 
        }
      }
      alert('do it!');
      for (var i = 0; i < mainDivs.length; ++i) {
        jQuery(mainDivs[i]).height(maxHeight); //Устанавливаем всем элементам максимальную высоту
      }
    }, 1000);
}

jQuery(window).on('load resize',myfunction);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: спасибо огромное!

Comment: @sashatexb, отметьте этот ответ как решение вопроса, если он решил вашу проблему.